# Modification of Riemann tensor by twisting the spin connection

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, supergravity

Suppose one has a funfbein $e^a_{\mu}$ with associated spin connection $\omega^\mu_{\,ab}$. Writing this in terms of differential forms,
$$e_a:=e_a^{\mu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu},\ \ \ \omega_{ab}:=\omega^\mu_{\,ab}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}$$
the Riemann tensor
$$R^a_{\ \,b}:=\frac{1}{2}R^a_{\ \,b\mu\nu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}\mathrm{d}x^{\nu}$$
is given by
$$R^{a}_{\ \,b}=\mathrm{d}\omega^a_{\ \,b}+\omega^a_{\ \,c}\land\omega^c_{\ \,b}.$$
All this is standard GR and I'm good with it. However, now consider a "twisted" torsionful spin connection
$$\tilde{\omega}_{ab}=\omega_{ab}-\frac{1}{4}e_f\epsilon^{fabcd}F_{cd},$$
where $F_{ab}=F_{\mu\nu}e^\mu_ae^\nu_b$ is the graviphoton field strength. (I do not know if "twisted" is necessarily the right technical term for this.) Call the new Riemann tensor associated to $\tilde{\omega}$ to be $\tilde{R}^a_{\ \,b}$. I can show that this will be given by
\begin{align}
\tilde{R}^{ab}=&R^{ab}-\frac{1}{4}\epsilon^{fabcd}(F_{cd}\mathrm{d}e_f+e_f\land\mathrm{d}F_{cd})\\
&-\frac{1}{2}\omega^{[a|}_{\ \ \ \,e}\land e_f\epsilon^{f|b]ecd}F_{cd}+\frac{1}{16}(F_{[cd}e_{f]})^2,
\end{align}
where $[...]$ denotes antisymmetrization of indices. However, I was wondering if there was a way to rewrite this entirely in terms of curvature tensors (Riemann, Ricci, and scalar) and the field strength $F$, without explicit reference to the funfbein or spin connection?

Comment: How "can [you] show" the this expression is the "right" curvature? What definition are you using here? The one you give above in terms of the connection is the only one I know.

Comment: What do you mean by "right" curvature? $\tilde{R}$ is calculated with the same formula as $R$ but with a different spin connection.

Comment: Oh, so you are trying to write the curvature with respect to one spin connection in terms of a different spin connection?